# Correct grouping with regex

Tags: regex

I have a regex which includes a list of commands. But I don't know what kind of parameter behind it is, so it can be a string or a number or nothing.
And there can be the possibility, that I don't know the command.

In my first version there wasn't any strings, so `(abc|def|[a-z]+)([0-9]*)` works fine. But now I want to allow strings, too. `(abc|def|[a-z]+)([0-9]*|[a-z]*)` doesn't work.

String 1: abc20def20ghi20
String 2: abcdddef20ghi20
String 3: abcdddef2d0ghi20abcdd

String 1:
Example with regex 1: **abc20***def20***ghi20**
Example with regex 2: **abc20***def20***ghi20**

String 2:
Example with regex 1: **abc***dddef20***ghi20**
Example with regex 2: **abc***dddef20***ghi20**

I want to get following result: **abc20***def20***ghi20** and **abcdd***def20***ghi20**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does the italics and the bold text mean?

Comment: That is not possible. Since the "commands" and the "parameters" are both composed of letters and there is no separator it's impossible to know when the command ends and the parameter begins. Or are there any other requirements for the commands and parameters? It seems that commands are always 3 characters long and parameters 2.

Comment: The bold and italic text means the recognized groups. Perhaps I have written to cloudy and should mention that I use RegexBuddy. Parameter and commands haven't specified length. In string 2 I have the command abc and the parameter dd. Only when I know the command the parameter is important. ghi isn't known as command so it isn't required to get the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your latest comment, maybe this will do the trick for you:

```
(abc|def)(\d+|(?:(?!(?1))[a-z])+)?|((?:(?!(?1))[a-z])+)((?2))?
```

EDIT. Oops, meant to edit my previous answer instead of posting new one.

TEST CASE:

```
<?php

$r = '#(abc|def)(\d+|(?:(?!(?1))[a-z])+)?|((?:(?!(?1))[a-z])+)((?2))?#';
$s1 = 'abc20def20ghi20';
$s2 = 'abcdddef20ghi20';
$s3 = 'abcdddef2d0ghi20abcdd';

preg_match_all($r, $s1, $m1);
preg_match_all($r, $s2, $m2);
preg_match_all($r, $s3, $m3);
var_dump($m1[0], $m2[0], $m3[0]);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "abc20"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "def20"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "ghi20"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "abcdd"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "def20"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "ghi20"
}
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "abcdd"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "def2"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "d0"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "ghi20"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "abcdd"
}
```

As you can see, it catches all parts from both strings correctly.

Comment: Nearly. :) I have thought about the lookahead, but I don't get it. The only thing is, that it doesn't work completly with String 1 the dd after abc will be ignored and the ghi is ignored in both Strings.

Comment: Okay, updated the regexp to take those cases into account, should work now. I also changed the look-ahead to use `(?1)` so you only need to edit the first command list if you want to add new commands.

Comment: Very nice work, but my RegexBuddy says that there are some errors and I don't know how to fix it. Simultaneous I developed your regex in a very simple version `(abc|def|[a-z]*).+?(?!(abc|def))`. :D

Comment: What regex flavor are you using? I tried with PCRE and it works. Might be that the `(?1)` aren't working in RegexBuddy, you can try to replace them with `(abc|def)`

Comment: I use PCRE with JGsoft program version 3.4.2. I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Here you can see the output of my RegexBuddy http://a.imageshack.us/img25/7753/regex.jpg

Comment: When ?1 your syntax for backreference 1 is, I fixed it. But it doesn't work finally. The regex forgets the 20 at the end of String 1 and in String 2 all numbers were ignored and the first two commands with parameter was take together. Sorry for my comments, but thanks for your help, yet!

Comment: You said that you don't need to get the parameter for "ghi" in your comment in your original question, so I left that part off. If you want to capture the 20 from the ghi as well, just change the last `[a-z]` to just `.` It should match all the parts correctly, I'll edit my answer with a test-case and the output.

Comment: Thanks very much! I found the solution `(abc|def)([0-9]+|(?:(?!(abc|def))[a-z])+)?|(?:(?!(abc|def)).)+`. I replaced the last [a-z] with the `([a-z]|[0-9])` to capture alphanumberic letters.

Comment: Yeah, changing to `([a-z]|[0-9])` does the same thing as changing it to just `.`. Btw you can just do `[a-z0-9]` instead of having two separate character classes.

Comment: The short edit time of a comment is annoying! My solution `(abc|def)([0-9]+|(?:(?!(abc|def))[a-z])+)?|(?:(?!(abc|def))[a-z]+[0-9]*)+` has a problem. It recognized abcdd def2 d0ghi20 abcdd and that isn't correct. d0ghi20 musst be splitted. I do this to force the order of the letters. First the alpha then the numbers. ;)

Comment: I have a new testcase. String 3: abcdddef2d0ghi20abcdd

Comment: I want it to def2 d0 ghi20 abcdd, when it is possible. :)

Comment: Updated the regexp + the test case. You might need to change the `(?1)` to `(asd|def)` and `(?2)` to `(\d+|(?:(?!(?1))[a-z])+)` if you try it with regexbuddy.

Comment: Perfect! It works :) So complex regex pattern I haven't created before! But I don't understand what the (?1) makes. When I replaced it with \1 for backreference it doesn't work.

Comment: (?1) is basically like a function call. (?1) is same as using the corresponding subpattern in its place. \1 refers to an already captured part.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps it isn't implemented in Java. I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Do you always want to capture strings whose length is 5? If so, you can do this:

```
([a-z]{3})([0-9a-z]{2})
```

If not, maybe you can clarify that what exactly is the criteria to "cut" the string between "abcdd" and "def20"?

Comment: No I'm sorry, but the commands and parameters haven't any specified length.